# Teradata String date to Date type change

Tags: sas, teradata

I have a Teradata query which I am running using SAS. Once of the Teradata fields I am trying to read has a series of digits which is in string format that basically refers to a date.
In the Teradata Field the value is 170919 which mean 2017-09-19.
I am unable to convert this value into a valid datetype.
Can you please help.

```
proc sql;
    connect to teradata (schema=&terasilo user=&terauser password=&terapass tdpid=&teradbase);
        create table COL_ASPECT_CALLS_2 as
            select * from connection to teradata(
                select 
                top 10 *
                from &&terasilo..DMI_COL_ASPECT_CALLS 
                where CAST(PROD_DATE_CH AS DATE FORMAT 'yymmdd')='2017-09-19'

                                          );
    disconnect from teradata;       
quit;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `PROD_DATE_CH ='170919'` instead of CASTing the string to a date`

Comment: I cannot use it as I need to give a date range Eg: 170919 to 171231. String value will not be easy to increment just like date columns.

Comment: @Dipyaman Character string in YYMMDD format can be tested using inequalities, unlike strings in MDY or DMY order. You could use format in SAS to generate character strings from date values. For example to create a macro variable that you could use in your Teradata query:  `%let nextmnth=%bquote('%sysfunc(intnx(month,&dateliteral,1,b),yymmddn6)');`. Once you have the string on the SAS side you can use INPUT function to convert it to a real date.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dealing with the century break setting or prepending `20` you can simply switch to `To_Date('170919', 'yymmdd')` which always assumes 21st century for two-digit years.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a system setting for Teradata that tells it how to convert 2 digit years.

But you could just add the century yourself. Perhaps just pre-pend '20'?

```
select
  CAST('170901' AS DATE FORMAT 'yymmdd') as NoCentury
, CAST('20'||'170901' AS DATE FORMAT 'yymmdd') as WithCentury
```

Yields

```
NoCentury   WithCentury
9/1/1917    9/1/2017
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. The code was meant to access Teradata fields through SAS. So after converting the field into a date field and then to use that field in the where condition, it only accepted date in the format 'yyyymmdd' (20170901) as opposed to (9/1/2017).

Comment: @Dipyaman I am not sure if you are asking a question or making a statement?  If you have a character field instead of the character literal in my example just use that `cast('20'||my_char_date as date format 'yymmdd') as my_real_date`. On the Teradata side you should be able to use date literals in the form `DATE'yyyy-mm-dd'`. On the SAS side you can attach any date format you want, but date literals require using DATE format like `'ddMONyyyy'd`.